# Virtual machine (ubuntu desktop) on a debian server

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtualbox, vmware-server

I want to install an 32bit ubuntu desktop on a 64bit debian server.
The host does not have any desktop environment installed and I don't want to install one but the virtual machine should be a desktop OS which will be used over VNC or similar protocols.
Is this possible without a host desktop?

What software should I use? I think I can use virtualbox and vmWare server but vmWare server is about 500MB and virtualbox is very small. VmWare seems to have a webinterface to controll the virtual machines which is quite nice since I have to start a virtualbox machine using ssh.
Which one would you use?

Answer (score 1):

quite possible, with vboxheadless or kvm (if the host is capable)
you can run the management GUI remotely if you like, using `ssh -X`

I personally have everything on KVM

Answer (score 0):

I would go for KVM in daemon mode. Then you can write an init script to start/stop it during runlevel change (i.e. system startup).

```
kvm -hda <guest.img> -vnc localhost:0 -daemonize
```

Then, on the client machine, setup a tunnel using SSH to `localhost:5900` (the VNC port KVM listens on the server machine) and connect through that tunnel using your favorite VNC client software.

```
ssh user@server -L 5900:localhost:5900 -T -N -f
vncviewer localhost:0
```

Keep in mind though that with this solution you should trust other users on the server since everyone who can log in via SSH would be able to connect to `localhost:5900`. I don't know of any way of setting a password in KVM's vnc server.

Answer (score 0):

Use **kvm** with accompanying **libvirt** and **virt-manager** interfaces. This will allow you to access the VM via remote VNC, just like you were at a monitor in front of the machine. You can even install Windows in it if you want to.

This [guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-a-debian-lenny-server) will tell you how to set-up kvm+libvirt on Debian.